# NameError: name 'Video' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I have little problem, I tryed make video uploader but something go wrong
models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Video
        fields=["name", "videofile"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Video
from .forms import VideoForm

def showvideo(request):

    lastvideo= Video.objects.last()

    videofile= lastvideo.videofile


    form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()


    context= {'videofile': videofile,
              'form': form
              }


    return render(request, 'Blog/videos.html', context)
```

And yes I made migrations but he telling me that name 'Video' is not defined

Comment: In your forms you did not import the `Video` model.

Answer (score 2):

In your `forms.py`, you specify `model = Video`, but you forgot to import the `Video` class, hence in that file, the name `Video` is *not* defined.

You can import this like:

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Video

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ["name", "videofile"]
```

Note that in your view, you should *not* write `form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)`, since then the form becomes invalid if there are simply nor `request.POST` parameters. You should pass `request.POST` itself, not `request.POST or None`.